# how to store image in sql using c# windows forms

Tags: c#, sql

i have a table like (id,name,image) and i want to know how to store and update  image in database .I read image by using OpenFileDialog , hope to help me friends.

Comment: this will show you an example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21208/Store-or-Save-images-in-SQL-Server

Comment: which database are you using!?

Comment: As a `VARBINARY(MAX)` or equivalent. Or, were you looking for code? (You'll have to give us a little more to work on here if that's the case)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
     [emp_id] [int] NOT NULL,
     [emp_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
     [emp_image] [image] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


string fileName = @"D:\MyImage.jpg";
string connectionString = "Password=PWD;Persist Security " + 
    "Info=True;User ID=USER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Data Source=SQLSERVER";
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

    FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    byte[] btImage = new byte[finfo.Length];
    FileStream fStream = finfo.OpenRead();

   fStream.Read(btImage, 0, btImage.Length);
  fStream.Close();


   using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Employee (emp_id, emp_name, " + 
        "emp_image) VALUES(@emp_id, @emp_name, @emp_image)", 
        sqlConnection))
   {

       sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", 2);
       sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_name", "Employee Name");
       SqlParameter imageParameter = 
             new SqlParameter("@emp_image", SqlDbType.Image);
       imageParameter.Value = btImage;

       sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(imageParameter);

       sqlConnection.Open();
       sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       sqlConnection.Close();
   }

}
```

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271591/Saving-an-image-to-a-SQL-Database-Table)

Comment: @user2536447 What you want?

Comment: AKA my real table contain about 40 columns is there another way to store image (mean directly or more easier ) and how to update images after saving

Answer (score 0):

One of the recommended ways of storing/retrieving images to/from sql is to use Base64 formats.

You can convert image to base64 string, save it to sql. Get back base64 string from sql, and convert it back to image.

[Here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx) is a link on how you can perform both conversions.

Answer (score 0):

you can make field in table datatype is varbinary(MAX) then you can save the image in ms sql using c#

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  picturePictureEdit.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    c.Picture = ms.ToArray();
}
```

if you get image from table you can write this code

```
if (c.Picture != null)
{
       byte[] newbit = c.Picture.ToArray();
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(newbit);
        picturePictureEdit.Image = new Bitmap(mem);

}

else
{
picturePictureEdit.Image = null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to serialize the image to a binary format that can be stored in a SQL BLOB column
Take a look at [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020929.asp)